Inequality involving liminf and limsup
Consider a bounded doubly indexed sequence $\{x_{nm}\}$ increasing in $m$ for each $n$. Is it correct that
$$
\liminf_{m\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{nm}\ge \limsup_{n\to\infty}\liminf_{m\to\infty}x_{nm}?
$$
or, at least,
$$
\liminf_{m\to\infty}\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{nm}\ge \liminf_{n\to\infty}\liminf_{m\to\infty}x_{nm}?
$$

If $L_n=\liminf_{m\to\infty}x_{nm}$, we know that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $M_n$ such that
$$
x_{nm}> L_n-\epsilon
$$
for each $m\ge M_n$. This seems to imply
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_{nm}\ge \limsup_{n\to\infty}L_n -\epsilon,
$$
which yields the result?

The only trouble with your argument is that $M_n$ may itself diverge, which makes the analysis you propose iffy. In fact, due to this, the statements can fail to hold.
As a counterexample, consider $$ x_{n,m} = \begin{cases}  1 - \frac1{m} & m > n,\\ -1 - \frac1{m} & m \le n \end{cases}. $$ For a fixed $n$, $x_{n,m}$ increases. But for every $m$, $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n,m} = -1-1/m,$$ so $$ \liminf_m \limsup_n x_{n,m} = -1, $$ while on the other hand $\limsup_{m} x_{n,m} = 1$ for every $n$. In fact, since the limits exist in each direction in this example, the second statement also fails for this sequence.

It's not increasing in $m$. For example take $n=3$: $$x_{3,1}=-1+\tfrac11=0,\qquad x_{3,2}=-1+\tfrac12=-\tfrac12$$

How about this instead? $$x_{n,m}=\tanh(m-n)$$

Oh, yes, I made a goof, thanks. But I think just $-1-1/m$  and $1 - 1/m$ would do. The $\tanh$ works just fine too, it seems :)
